# Including custom typings in JHipster (v5.82) project

Tags: javascript, angular, jhipster, typescript-typings, metronic

The basic idea is to start with a new JHipster project (v5.8.2) and integrate the Metronic Angular theme in it.
I haven't found much in the way of documentation for this task, but sluggishly I've integrated the various css/js bundles, the components, however I ran across a problem with some of their directives.
So basically in **toggle.directive.ts** after the view initiates it tries to create a new KTToggle see

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.toggle = new KTToggle(this.el.nativeElement, this.options);
}
```

KTToggle is defined in **scripts.bundle.js** that I've already imported in **vendor.ts**.
I've also copied **typings.d.ts** file from metronic in *src/main/webapp/app*.

The problem is that it doesn't find KTToggle, when running *npm run webpack:build* I get no error, but when actually trying to access the page I get

```
ERROR ReferenceError: "KTToggle is not defined"
```

Additionally in IntelliJ I get the following error

```
TS2350: Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword
```

I tried to declare **KTToggle** straight in the directive

```
declare var KTToggle: any;
```

But this give me the same ReferenceError.
Also in **tsconfig.json** I tried to point to the typings file through *typeRoots*, *types*, *files* all gave me either the same error or for *types* caused other parts of the app to fail.

I'm not too experienced with Angular/Webpack but I suspect the typing is not properly loaded, because if I try to go to the definition of **KTToggle** in IntelliJ it points me to the **scripts.bundle.js** file.

I welcome any kind of help, thank you.

Additional info:

**typings.d.ts**

```
    /* SystemJS module definition */
declare var module: NodeModule;
interface NodeModule {
    id: string;
}

declare var KTMenu: any;
declare var KTOffcanvas: any;
declare var KTScrolltop: any;
declare var KTHeader: any;
declare var KTToggle: any;
declare var KTUtil: any;
declare var KTPortlet: any;
declare var KTDialog: any;
declare var Chart: any;
```

**scripts.bundle.js**

```
.....    
KTToggle=function(t,e){var n=this,i=KTUtil.get(t);KTUtil.get("body");if(i){var o={togglerState:"",targetState:""}
....
```

L.E. 2020-04-11
What we ended up doing was setting a new entry point in the the webpack configuration file (both dev and prod), like this:

```js
    entry: {
        global: './src/main/webapp/content/scss/global.scss',
        main: './src/main/webapp/app/app.main',
        // metronic scripts bundled, contains needed JS for Metronic functionalities
        metronicScripts: [
            './src/main/webapp/content/metronic/assets/demo/default/base/scripts.bundle.js'
        ]
    },
```

and then in the common webpack configuration we modified the **HtmlWebpackPlugin** to include the new chunk like so:

```js
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/main/webapp/index.html',
            chunks: [
                // include metronic bundle before the main bundle so that we can utilize metronic variables in components and initialize the layout for example
                'metronicScripts'
                ,'polyfills'
                ,'main'
                ,'global'
            ],
            chunksSortMode: 'manual',
            inject: 'body'
        }),
```

Afterwards we could use the various elements from metronic inside components like so

```js
...
declar var KTUtil: any;

@Component({...})
...
ngOnInit() {
   KTUtil.init();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(ERROR ReferenceError: "KTToggle is not defined") mean you not load the script file **toggle.js**,

So make sure you load all what Metronic loaded in index.html file and not delete imports of it, by default Metronic load this files in index.html :

```
<script src="assets/js/global/components/base/util.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/global/components/base/header.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/global/components/base/menu.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/global/components/base/offcanvas.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/global/components/base/scrolltop.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/global/components/base/toggle.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/global/components/base/dialog.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/js/global/components/base/wizard.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For someone stumbling upon this question, looking for answers, adding the reference to bundled files in angular.json file, resolved the issue for me.

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            ....
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/vendors/global/vendors.bundle.js",
              "src/assets/js/demo1/scripts.bundle.js"
            ],
            ..
          }
..
}
```